# NextJS create-next-app not working properly

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, npx

I have installed NextJS using both methods `npm install next react react-dom` and `npx create-next-app appname` multiple times, but the directories are supposed to look like:

`pages, api(_app.js, index.js), public, styles,  .next, node_modules`

But in MY project they look like:
`components, pages (index.js only), static, .next, node_modules`

I saw multiple installation procedures but they all give the same project directories (latter) TO ME, and the former directories in their tutorials. I cannot follow any tutorials on nextjs due to this!

Comment: usually when I see something like this, it's because the documentation (or tutorial, or article) is using a different version from you.  See if you can figure out what version they're using in the materials you are referencing and compare it to what version you have now.

Comment: All the tuts I found had ^ and latest for the node npm, and other pkg versions, so that's why I am not sure about going to older versions yet.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [on this GitHub issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/18188) !

`npm i -g create-next-app`

If it says files already exist, try adding `--force` to the command above. It worked for me, I don't know how, but it did!